# Error importing BeautifulSoup - Conflict with Python version

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, easy-install

I installed BeautifulSoup with the command:

```
sudo easy_install BeautifulSoup4
```

I got the message:

```
Searching for BeautifulSoup4
Best match: beautifulsoup4 4.1.3
Processing beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.6.egg
beautifulsoup4 4.1.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for BeautifulSoup4
Finished processing dependencies for BeautifulSoup4
```

I'm trying to import the BeautifulSoup lib.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

or:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

My Python version is:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

**EDIT**

I understand that:

```
Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.6.egg
```

Could mean that there is a conflict between the versions of Python

How can I have this module registered? Thanks

Comment: this line from your question should give you a clue: `Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.6.egg`

Comment: The system Python is 2.7 - but your easy_install installs for 2.6....

Comment: I understand the issue, do I have to update first easy_install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I discovered that this solve the issue:

```
pip uninstall BeautifulSoup4
```

will uninstall the package that is in:

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/
```

And:

```
easy_install-2.7 BeautifulSoup4
```

will successfully install the package in:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I've checked the process also with some other packages having the same issues and it works.

Answer (score 4):

It should be,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: The result is the same: ImportError: No module named bs4

Comment: @maxdangelo Do you have two different version of python installed in your machine?

Comment: I don't think so, I've updated python from 2.6 (That is coming by default in my macos 10.6.8 installation) to 2.7.

Comment: @maxdangelo search for the file BeautifulSoup.py in your system. It should be there in your dist-packages or site-packages directory.

Comment: there is not a file with this name in my system.

Comment: @maxdangelo Please try to re-install it with pip instead of easy_install. "sudo pip install BeautifulSoup". To use pip you need to install setup-tools module.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): BeautifulSoup4 in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3-py2.6.egg I unfortunately think that in my installation there is a conflict between the original version of Python coming with OS 10.6 and the 2.7.3 that I've installed. I'm planning to delete both the version and install a clean one. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

- `easy_install pip`
- When that is done, restart, and type in `pip install beautifulsoup4`. That should work.

Make sure that you have it as a module with `pip list`, if you see Beautiful Soup as an output, then yes, you have it working.

Comment: Hi, I've installed pip. after a pip list the module is present but the importing is still giving an error.

Comment: @maxdangelo : Then check your paths, there probably is a problem there.

Answer (score -3):

You have to also

```
pip install bs4
```

and use

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```