# BeautifulSoup import error in python 2.7 Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, windows-7-x64

I'm new with Python and I'm trying to use the BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 package but I get the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PythonPruebas\src\prueba.py", line 10, in <module>
       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup        
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

line 10 is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

- I have uninstalled and reinstalled it but it doesn't works.
- I installed it using setup.py install.
- I don't have other versions of python in my PC.
- When I write the same line in IDLE (Python GUI), nothing happens I only get the error in NetBeans.

Comment: Did you try it with pip yet?

Comment: How have you installed `BeautifulSoup`? What is the output of `pip freeze` command? Thanks.

Comment: I installed the first time using setup.py then I used pip but it doesn't works. The output of pip freeze is: beautifulsoup4==4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You should install it like `pip install BeautifulSoup4` , if you don't have `pip` installed, install it like it's written in this post (there are several workable solutions) [How to install pip on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: what is wrong with the answer? why down-vote? Please, explain. Is there the same error after `pip install BeautifulSoup4` ?

Comment: Hi, I don't know who down-vote your answer, it wasn't me. I have used pip and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here.

[Error importing BeautifulSoup - Conflict with Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170902/error-importing-beautifulsoup-conflict-with-python-version)

I had to change my import to "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup."