# Cannot import Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup, and despite using the import statement:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

I am getting the error: `ImportError: cannot import name BeautifulSoup`

`import bs4` does not give any errors.

I have also tried `import bs4.BeautifulSoup` and just importing bs4 and creating a BeautifulSoup object with: `bs4.BeautifulSoup()`

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: what operating system are you using? how did you install python? how did you install beautifulsoup4?

Comment: does `import BeautifulSoup` work?

Comment: I am on a Linux server. I'm not sure about how either were installed as I am not an admin. I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas because I can not speak with an administrator until tomorrow.

Comment: try `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` . Also, check if you have really installed it

Comment: If `import bs4` works, what does `dir(bs4)` print?  This will be a list of all the components (functions, classes, submodules, etc.) in `bs4`.

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16349505/4720017

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue was I named the file `HTMLParser.py` , and that name is already used somewhere in the bs4 module.

Thanks to everyone that helped!

Comment: Same thing happened to me, my Python file was called 'bs4.py' which threw the error.

Comment: the same error happened to me when I inadvertently deleted `__init__.py` from the bs4 site-packages folder. Even though I ran `pip uninstall bs4` and then `pip install bs4`, it didn't restore that file.

Answer (score 8):

I found out after numerous attempts to solve the `ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup4'` that the package is actually called `BeautifulSoup` so the import should be:

**`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`**

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` is already mentioned in OP's question.

Comment: Another breaking change, this answer is correct currently *at this time*.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the directory from which you are running your script does not contain a filename called bs4.py.

Comment: Thank you. I was pulling my hair.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by installing beautifulsoup4, the "4" is essential.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Yes it works using `pip install beautifulsoup4` and then import `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4`

Answer (score 3):

I experienced a variation of this problem and am posting for others' benefit.

I named my Python example script `bs4.py`

Inside this script, whenever trying to import bs4 using the command:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, an `ImportError` was thrown, but confusingly (for me) the import worked perfectly from an interactive shell within the same venv environment.

After renaming the Python script, imports work as expected. The error was caused as Python tries to import itself from the local directory rather than using the system copy of bs4

Comment: file name... thats exactly right. That solved my problem too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Copy **bs4** and **beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info** from **C:\python\Lib\site-packages** to your local project directory. It worked for me. Here, python actually looks for the library in local directory rather than the place where the library was installed!

Comment: Not sure about this one. Tried it didn't work for me and also not making sense to me. Cause from my understanding the python program runs from your python environment if the environment already has the python library why would putting in the project directory change anything?

Answer (score 2):

The **bs4** and **beautifulsoup4** folders might be in the **site-packages folder**. So copy BeautifulSoup4 folder in bs4 and then try the below code. It worked for me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Since you were importing BeautifulSoup from bs4 and in bs4 there was no BeautifulSoup folder. That is why it was showing `ImportError: cannot import name BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reason: If you have more than one python versions installed and let's say you installed beautifulsoup4 using pip3, it will only be available for import when you run it in python3 shell.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this type error in the beginning even after install all the modules which were required including `pip` install `bs4` (if you have installed this then no need to install `beautifusoup4 | BeautifulSoup4` through `pip` or anywhere else it comes with `bs4` itself)

Solution : Just go to your python file where it is installed  `C:\python\Lib\site-packages`
and then copy `bs4` and `beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info` folders and paste it to your project folder where you have saved your working project.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve is, while creating your interpreter select your global python path on your system(/usr/local/bin/python3.7).
Make sure that in pycharm shell, python --version appears as 3.7. It shouldn't show 2.7

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with package just need to Copy **bs4** and
**beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info** into your project directory

Answer (score 0):

When I used

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

instead of

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

it returned that all requirements already satisfied but I ran it again and it worked, I'm using a virtualenv which uses python 3.8.10, I don't really know the logic behind it but hey it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The error was that the file in which I was importing beautifulsoup from bs4 was in another folder. Just replaced the file out of the internal folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that might have the same issue as me. I tried all the above, but still didn't work. issue was 1 was using a virtual environment so needed to do pip install in the pycharm terminal instead of a command prompt to install it there. Secondly I had typed import Beautifulsoup with the S not capitalized. changed to BeautifulSoup and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a permissions issue. Directory "/usr/local/lib/python#.#/site-packages/bs4" was only 'rwx' by root and no other groups/users.  Please check permissions on that directory.

Answer (score -1):

Another potential issue could be the case sensitivity.

Correct 
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Incorrect 
`from bs4 import Beautifulsoup`